# PhpStorm: what does it mean the name of the folder in square brackets along with the name of a folder?

Tags: phpstorm

The root of my PhpStorm projects is `app-project-name-www`.

In all my other projects, PhpStorms shows the root with this name:

```
app-project-name-www [app-project-name-www]
```

In this project, instead, it adds the square brackets to the `tests` folder, like you can see in the image below.

### Questions

1. What does it indicate the name in the square brackets?
2. How does it call PhpStorm? (I'm not able to search for info in Google as I don't know what to search for)
3. How to put this name again along with the root folder, removing it from the `tests` folder?

*Current PhpStorm version: 2020.1.3*

[image]

Comment: Is your `app-project-name-www` the upper most in the hierarchy? I imagine that these brackets are there to distinguish the folder from another module, to remove any doubt of what the test directory is testing exactly.

Comment: I think that there is an error in configuration.

In other projects, the square brackets are along with the root of the project, the main folder, the one in which all other files and folders are (including tests).

In this case, instead, it seems that PHPStorm gone one level down, reaching `tests` and marking it with the square brackets, but this is wrong (and is for sure a misconfiguration that I made - but don't know how, as I didn't touch the PHPStorm config, but simply installed Codeception).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These brackets likely indicate that your `tests` folder is added as an additional content root to your project. Check **Preferences | Directories**

Comment: Yes, it was added as content root, but it was the last item in the very long list that I have (due to dependencies in `vendor`)! Thank you for the solution!